# Infinite loop using cin and do-while, even when using cin.sync to flush the buffer

Tags: c++, validation, cin

I'm trying input validation in the following piece of code:

```
typedef unsigned long DATATYPE;
typedef unsigned long ADDRTYPE;
enum {READ_MEMORY, WRITE_MEMORY, PRINT_CACHE, PRINT_MEMORY, EXIT};
typedef bool BOOL;

typedef struct
{
   ADDRTYPE  nRamSize;
   DATATYPE* pMemory;
} MEMORY;

typedef struct
{
   DATATYPE data[CACHELINE_SIZE_BYTES];
   ADDRTYPE tag;
   BOOL     bValid;
} CACHELINE;

typedef struct
{
   CACHELINE CacheLine[SET_ASSOCIATIVITY];
} CACHESET;

typedef struct
{
   ADDRTYPE  nNumSets;   // Stores the number of sets in the cache
   CACHESET* pCacheSet;  // Each set contains SET_ASSOCIATIVITY slots
} SETASSOCCACHE;

int isPowerOfTwo(ADDRTYPE x)
{
   return (x != 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    int           nChoice;
    ADDRTYPE      nCacheSize;
    MEMORY        Memory;
    SETASSOCCACHE Cache;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter size of memory in bytes (has to be a power of 2)" << endl;
        cin >> Memory.nRamSize;
        cin.sync();
    } while (!isPowerOfTwo(Memory.nRamSize)); // Keep taking in values till its a power of 2

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter size of cache in bytes (has to be a power of 2)" << endl;
        cin >> nCacheSize;
        cin.sync();
     } while (!isPowerOfTwo(nCacheSize)); // Keep taking in values till its a power of 2
}
```

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/sync/), using cin.sync() should get rid of any trailing newlines in the user input. But, even with that, I'm STILL getting a infinite loop after the first input. Any ideas I'm overlooking something obvious ?

Some more info:

- This is on a Mac OSX, using gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
- The terminal used for inputs is the Terminal.app supplied by apple (also on iTerm2).

EDIT - I'm beginning to think this is something peculiar to the g++ installed with XCode 4.1 in Mac OS X Lion - I ran the same code on my office linux machine, and it didn't show this weirdness (also, none of the other folks seem to have reproduced the error). It would be nice if someone has Lion XCode, and could try out Brian's example to see if they get an infinite loop when the first input is a non-power of 2.

Thanks everyone for jumping in !!

Comment: Which loop loops infinitely? And what is this `MEMORY` type?

Comment: Can we see what MEMORY is defined as?  I tried the same code using flat ints and it works fine for me.  edit: also what's an ADDRTYPE

Comment: The code is perfectly fine even without the `sync`. I'm pretty sure you enter something wrong from the keyboard - some letter or invalid number.

Comment: Updated with structure definitions

Comment: Also, all I'm entering is 1024 followed by enter (tried with 2048 as well). I'm simply not seeing what I'm doing wrong !!

Comment: Aaah, these all-capital-letters type names burn my eyes..

Comment: I can't believe, that this is your real code and you really enter 1024. Did you try exactly the same code, as posted here (without anything else) ?

Comment: @Kiril - with the example posted by Brian, I still get the infinite loop if i enter a non-power of 2. I'm convinced something is wrong with the Mac terminal / g++ being used, as that is the only thing I'm unfamiliar with!!

Comment: @shan23 - did you try without `sync`?

Comment: @Kiril - wow, without cin.sync(), it works fine - whereas, its supposed to be the reverse !

Comment: @shan23 - I just added it as answer. My guess is that `sync` confuses the input of a number. I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reduce your code to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) you'll find that there's no problem:

```
#include <iostream>

int isPowerOfTwo(unsigned long x)
{
   return (x != 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long nChoice;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter size of memory in bytes (has to be a power of 2)" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> nChoice;
        std::cin.sync();
    } while (!isPowerOfTwo(nChoice)); // Keep taking in values till its a power of 2

}
```

This works exactly as expected, therefore the code you posted isn't the actual code exhibiting a problem, or there's something screwy in your types.

**EDIT:** To explain why entering a non-number causes the loop to spiral out of control, see:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.2

Once invalid input is given, it won't try and read again.

The following will fix these issues (from the FAQ):

```
while ((std::cout << "Enter size of memory in bytes (has to be a power of 2)" << std::endl)
       && !(std::cin >> nChoice))
{
   std::cin.clear();
   std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

When the read into `nChoice` fails, the character is left in the stream. You have to reset the stream state, then remove the offending characters from the stream with `ignore()`

Comment: This is interesting - I ran your example on my setup (detailed in the post). If I enter a valid input (power of 2), all is well. However, if I don't, and enter a non-power of 2, I still get the infinite loop !! Does that make any sense ?

Comment: +1 (though I'll mention that `ADDRTYPE` was `unsigned long` and not `int`)

Comment: @HostileFork - I posted this before he added all the types to his post; changing now.

Comment: The infinite loop happens when `cin >> nChoice fails`, for example if you type 'a'.

Comment: @Brian - You didn't get my point. At each loop, it DOES NOT ask for input :), thus giving the user no chance to edit the input and get it right.

Comment: @jrok - Ahh - I see what he/you mean now.

Comment: @shan23 Then there's something else wrong. Your code (and Brian's) works as expected as long as cin sucessfully reads a number.

Comment: @I tried Kirils suggestion - removing cin.sync() makes the example program work for me !! Is this a bug in the mac gcc (I doubt it, but still...doesn't seem like a feature !!)

Comment: @shan: Try `cin.clear();`. If any error flags are set the stream will stop providing input.

Comment: @Xeo - I just tried that thinking it would fix his problem, no joy.

Comment: +1. I'd add that `cin.sync()` obviously doesn't discard what's left in the stream once it's in `fail()` state.

Comment: @Brian - Perfect !! Thanks for the FAQ link - I'm wondering how many have learned the idiosyncracies of cin() the hard way (like I did now !!).

Answer (score 1):

The code is perfectly fine without `sync`.

I guess `sync` "breaks" the code because of the `new line` character at the end. Once you enter a "good" number(power of 2), everything is fine. If it's not power of two, your code goes through `sync` which seems to confuses the `cin`, as you try to read a number.

Comment: Shouldn't this be considered as a bug in gcc ?

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt it. You may want to check the _badbit_ flag when you go through `sync`. Try to debug/print it to see if it's raised.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the appropriate info and link to the faq. It's working as intended (not a bug); you have to clear the failed stream state and get rid of the non-numeric characters in the stream. You don't need sync() at all.